# Defining a functions that doubles the first number and triples the second one in Python

Tags: python, function

I have tried this code:

```
def double_and_triple(num1, num2):
   double = num1 * 2
   triple = num2 * 3
   print("the double of {} is {}, while the triple of {} is {}" .format(num1, double, num2, triple)
   return double, triple    
result = double_and_triple(5, 10)
```

But it gives me a syntax error in the 5th and 6th lines.

I have tried to substitute `return` with a `pass` or skipping the line altogether but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Look closely at the end of the previous line. Think carefully about how the line should end instead.

Comment: There is a space before `.format`

Comment: @go2nirvana the space does not matter. A closing `)` is missing

Comment: @Scotty1- Space - is exactly the problem and closing `)` is not missing.

Comment: @go2nirvana no. trust me. the space is NOT the problem. just try it yourself: `'{0}' .format(5)`. this works fine. this is correct, but not encouraged, python/pep8 syntax. The closing `)` is not missing (anymore), because I added it in an edit.

Comment: @Scotty1- Adding it in an edit was unfortunate.

Comment: @Scotty1- Since the syntax error was most likely the problem in this case, I doubt fixing the problem *in the question* is a good idea. FYI I've rolled back your edit.

Comment: Imho this is not a question suitable for SO. As pointed out in the closing-vote, typos are not what SO is intended for. Thus I think editing non-SO-related issues is quite ok. I'd never answer a question which is suited for SO by editing, but in this case...

Comment: Obviously if the typo is the cause of the OP's problem, and you edit it out, then the question will make no sense. You'll make it harder for anyone else to identify the problem (and harder to close the question as a typo if that is appropriate).

Comment: the problem was the missing ), I tired both with and without the space before .format and both work

Comment: I'm sorry this wasn't an appropriate question for this site, I didn't think it was so easy. Where else could I ask my questions in the future should there be others? I'm teaching myself so I don't have a guide

Comment: @julyjuly https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

code:

```
def double_and_triple(num1, num2):
       double = num1 * 2
       triple = num2 * 3
       print("the double of {} is {}, while the triple of {} is {}" .format(num1, double, num2, triple))
       return double, triple    
result1,result2 = double_and_triple(5, 10)
```

output:

```
the double of 5 is 10, while the triple of 10 is 30
```

Comment: To show the usage of f-strings: `print(f"the double of {num1} is {double}, while the triple of {num2} is {triple}")`  or even `print(f"the double of {num1} is {num1 * 2}, while the triple of {num2} is {num2 * 3}")`